# How to set a fixed unit to size aesthetic in geom_segment?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some troubles with the size aesthetic of geom_segment. I would like to set the size aes to a fixed unit (for example, inches) to avoid scaling problems.

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
fakedata <- data.frame(a=c(20, 2),
                   b=c(30, 4),
                   c=c(1,2))

ggplot(fakedata, aes(x=a, y=c)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x=a, xend=b,
                     y=as.numeric(c), yend=as.numeric(c)), 
                 size=100, color="black", alpha=.4) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1.5), color="yellow") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=2.5), color="yellow") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.5), color="yellow")
```

I put some yellow lines to illustrate the scaling problem.

PNG output 500x500px:

[image: png 500x500px]

PNG output 400x400px:

[image: png 400x400px]

As we can see in the pictures, the yellow markers are in the expected place but the gray boxes have a different size in the second picture.

Note: for this small example, there is a possible solution using geom_rect. But in out real (and bigger) problem we cannot use geom_rect anymore, so a fixed size geom_segment could help.

Comment: `geom_rect` seems like a sensible way to draw a rectangle, can you elaborate on why it's unsuitable?

Comment: the short answer to your query is no. ggplot2 uses relative units in the plot panel, and while there are possible workarounds to get absolute sizes, they're generally not recommendable and of limited applicability.

Comment: Thank you @baptiste
Sometimes we use `plotly`, and in this case, `geom_segment` seems to be much faster.